# How to run Asp.Net Core Application packaged as a Linux docker container with code coverage?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, code-coverage

Our App runs in a linux docker container deployed to an Azure App Service.

We have a QA pod for which we would like to collect the code coverage data. To the best of my understanding it means:

1. Running kestrel from within a coverage tool. We use built-in .NET coverage collector when we run our unit tests during the CI builds. It is unclear how to leverage it here, if at all possible. We could probably use OpenCover for this, but the details are unclear.
2. The coverage report needs to be persisted somewhere for us to pick up and publish on our on-prem SonarQube server. It is unclear how to cause this report to be generated without stopping the app service.

We do all this in order to augment the coverage figures from unit tests with those from automated E2E tests.